# LLVM compiler - How Can I Disable Optimization on a Specific Function?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, llvm

I have a problem when optimizing code, and it seams that the reason is an inline function.
Is there a way to prevent optimization of an inline function?

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625624).

Comment: It could be a bug in the optimizer, but it could also be a bug in the code. When a program has undefined behavior one result could be that it works fine without optimization off but crashes with optimization. Try enabling more warnings and turning on features like `-fcatch-undefined-behavior` and `-ftrapv`

Comment: where should i put these flags?

Comment: @ErikSapir in the build settings for the project they should go in the 'other C++ flags' area, I think. (You're lucky I saw this. I didn't get any notification because you didn't say @bames53)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will stop a function being inlined:

```
__attribute__((noinline))
void method(int a) {
    // Blah
}
```

If you mean actual optimisation level, then look at [the question @zoul referred to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625624).