# Optimizer strangeness on devices running 4.2.1

Tags: iphone, ios

When compiler optimizations are turned on
this line:

```
NSLog(@"start point : %@, line start x: %f, line start y: %f", NSStringFromCGPoint(staffLineStart), staffLineStart.x, staffLineStart.y);
```

yields

start point : {20, **88**}, line start x: 20.000000, line start y: **20.000000**

**Edit 1:**
I've worked around the problem by inlining the method that populated CGPoint staffLineStart.

Bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a weird armv6 optimization bug that I especially noticed on my apps running on iOS 4.2.1, it occurred when I did a line like this:

```
newView.bounds = oldView.bounds;
```

If you do not want to modify the original source, you can always go into the build phases and set the compiler flags to -O0 for the source files that are causing the problem.  See this SO question for more information:

[Trouble disabling LLVM optimizations via pragma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625624/trouble-disabling-llvm-optimizations-via-pragma)